# Karma/PhantomJS Disconnect on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, karma-runner

Recently, if I do 2-3 builds in succession on Jenkins, my Karma task fails for the following reason:

> Running "karma:jenkins" (karma) task
>   [32m13 02 2017 16:46:00.876:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9018/
>   [32m13 02 2017 16:46:00.878:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
>   [32m13 02 2017 16:46:00.885:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
>   [32m13 02 2017 16:46:01.345:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket /#lF481tq-G7blX6hpAAAA with id 85942733
>   [33m13 02 2017 16:46:11.346:WARN [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mDisconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.

This is happening for me for both Karma: 1.3.0 AND 1.4.1.  Same PhantomJS version on both builds.  NPM version: 3.10.10

I've tried specifying the host, the address, and extending the timeout.  I'm out of solutions, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this and if so, what did you have to do Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not, current'y we don't have Karma running automatically on our headless machine.